# How to use both eureka-js-client and node-server for crud operations on my json stored in a file?

Tags: registry, netflix-eureka, eureka-js-client

Below example is demonstrating how to use eureka-js-client using eureka registry
https://github.com/zilehuda/eureka-zuul-nodejs-microservices/tree/master/user-service

and below example demonstrating how to use node-server using npm
https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-13-tutorial/build-json-rest-api

Already I have Eureka Registry in port 8761
and gateway, and other java based microservices registered to it.

I would like to create a simple node application, to contain input json file to act as database.
Would like to use node-server for crud operations on it.
At the same time, also I want this node-server registered to Eureka registry
How can I accompolish this?
Any working examples or inputs could be appreciable.

I have implemented angular13 based node-server but not clear what to do , to register it with Eureka registery using eureka-js-client here
because, there is no specific code from out node js program, simply node run node-server with json file name as input is directly exporting port

not clear, how to find app for the eureka-js-client here

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Using command

`json-server --watch ./server/database.json`

able to start a server, say at port 300

now using another file: `register-to-eureka.js` with below content

```
const eurekaHelper = require('./eureka-helper');
eurekaHelper.registerWithEureka('products-catalog', 3000);
```

able to register the client to register.

It is really quite a simple.

next step could be to learn, how to add security layer ( i.e., `user/role/permission` driven access to each operations of the node-server).